# Making nested http requests java asynchronous

Tags: java, lambda, playframework, java-8

I am using play java for my project(java play ws API) and

```
private CompletionStage<String> getAuthToken() {
    WSRequest request = ws.url(URL);
    WSRequest complexRequest = request.setHeader("X-API-Key", X_API_KEY)
            .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE)
            .setHeader(AUTHORIZATION, CLIENT_DETAILS_BASE64_ENCODE);
    CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = complexRequest.post(GRANT_TYPE + "="
            + PASSWORD + "&" + USERNAME + "=" + USERNAME + "&" + PASSWORD + "=" + PASSWORD);
    return responsePromise.thenApply(response-> getAuthToken2().toString());
}

private CompletionStage<String> getAuthToken2() {
    WSRequest request = ws.url(URL);
    WSRequest complexRequest = request.setHeader("X-API-Key", X_API_KEY)
            .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE)
            .setHeader(AUTHORIZATION, CLIENT_DETAILS_BASE64_ENCODE);
    CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = complexRequest.post(GRANT_TYPE + "="
            + PASSWORD + "&" + USERNAME + "=" + USERNAME + "&" + PASSWORD + "=" + PASSWORD);
    return responsePromise.thenApply(response-> addIdentity(response.asJson().findValue("access_token").toString()).toString());
}
```

What is the mistake I am making? How do I make nested requests one after the other one?

I get

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@75c6e852[Not completed]
```

as the response to my client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `thenCompose` to chain multiple http requests. Here is a working sample: for three sites, we will fetch their page and add the status code to a JSON object. At the end, we return that object.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getSites() {
    ObjectNode hosts = Json.newObject();
    return ws.url("https://www.facebook.com").get()
            .thenCompose(res ->  {
                hosts.put("facebook", res.getStatus());
                return ws.url("https://www.google.com").get();
            })
            .thenCompose(res -> {
                hosts.put("google", res.getStatus());
                return ws.url("https://www.twitter.com").get();
            })
            .thenApply(res -> {
                hosts.put("twitter", res.getStatus());
                return ok(hosts);
            });
    }
```